# Is it possible to create a terminal command alias to automate CTRL + ALT + SYSRQ + R-E-I-S-U-O keypresses?

Tags: shutdown, reboot

For whatever reason, my external harddrive pretty regularly experiences initramfs issues on boot, causing me to run `$ fsck /dev/sdb2 -y` to bring everything back in line.

One thing I have noticed though, is that shutting down or restarting the system with the titled command greatly reduces the occurrence of this error.

Is there any way to create a script or terminal alias that would "go through the motions" of pressing those keys (with a small delay between each letter)? So rather than play digital gymnastics with my fingers and toes, I could simply type `$ reisuo` and it would go through the motions for me?

Comment: After this has sent `TERM` and `KILL` signals to all processes, how do you expect the _rest_ of such a script to continue running?

Comment: Hello @JdeBP! You raise a very good point. Are you saying, then, that perhaps this type of command "must" be manually typed out for that reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

for c in r s u o; do
  echo $c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
  sleep 1
done
```

(Though, the CTRL key is not simulated, and it has no effect anyway)

Edit: removed `e i` since they kill processes, including current shell and the rest of the script would not continue. You would be better off using `kill` or `slay` anyway. And when you are doing `SysRQ s u o`, `r` is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you @Radovan! What would I need to research to learn what is being programmed here? Is this a type of shell programming or something?

Comment: Yes it is shell programming. The for loop makes the variable called `c` take each of the values in turn. The `echo $c` outputs the value of the c variable to the special `sysrq-trigger` `file` provided by the kernel to trigger the same routines that the keyboard sequences do. The `sleep 1` makes the program pause for (at least, but usually not significantly more than) one second. The `do` and `done` delimit the command to be done for each value of the variable `c`.

Comment: @icarus Whenever I try to the run the above script, I receive the following notice "cannot create /proc/sysrq-trigger: Permission denied". Running `ls -lh` on the file returns `-rwx------ linux root`. "linux" is the name of my current login... Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: It would seem a lot simpler to just use the `sync` and `umount`/`mount` commands.

Comment: Instead of using `reisuo` to run the script, use `sudo reisuo` to run it. It should also be possible to alter the udev rules to change the permissions on the file.

Comment: @Spectator6: that indicates the `/proc` virtual filesystem has not been mounted (yet?), and as a result, `/proc` is just an empty directory (mountpoint) to which the `echo` command creates a file. Normally `/proc` is a virtual filesystem that is essentially a "view" of kernel's process table and other internal state information; it does not exist on disk at all. But if that has not been mounted, that indicates a problem **very** early in the boot process.

Answer (score 1):

For those like me who may be new to shell scripting, here's a step-by-step for how I was able to get @Radovan's script up and running:

1. `$ cd /usr/local/bin` This is where the scripts will be saved. Saving scripts in this directory does NOT require adding new PATHS.
2. `sudo vim rsuo.sh` To properly interact with this directory, the script will need to be created with sudo privileges
3. Add @Radovan's script above which, thanks to @JdeBP's great advice, now omits the the SIGTERM and SIGKILL commands so the script is able to run to completion
4. After saving the file, its permissions need to be expanded so the non-root user can access it, with the following commands: `$ sudo chmod u+x rsuo.sh` and/or `$ sudo chown <user_name> rsuo.sh`
5. Now that the file is all set, to create an alias for the command, open the .bashrc (`$ vim ~/.bashrc`) and add `alias rsuo="cd /usr/local/bin && sudo rsuo.sh"`
6. Once that's saved, close and restart your terminal, and when you type `$ rsuo`, it will prompt you for your sudo password, then execute the script.
7. I repeated the above steps for the rsub command, that way I can also have a way to reboot the system.
8. Consume Double Stuf Oreos to your liking ;)

Comment: In step 4, the `chmod` is mandatory and the `chown` is unnecessary.  If `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` (as stated in step 1), then you don’t need to do `cd /usr/local/bin` in step 5.